# Using crop feature withut initial upload to s3

Tags: filepicker.io

We are implementing a crop feature on our image uploads.

Here are the sequence of events.

```
1a)We call Filepicker.pick method to upload file to filepicker, 
1b)Then filepicker uploads it to s3. 
2a)Then we call filepicker.stat method to get dimensions.
2b)Then we call filepicker.convert to get small preview image and set that in crop dialog on the user end.
3a)When user adjusts the cropping area using jquery, we capture the dimensions.
3b)Then when user presses the crop button, we call filepicker.crop to get the cropped image.
4a)After that we call filepicker.convet to get 3 sizes. Thumb, small, medium.
5a) Then we move these images to S3 upon save on the user end.
```

Our end goal is that our user experience while uploading/cropping a file goes smoothly and as fast as possible. Currently this is a challenge, and the whole process is slow. So we are trying to eliminiate step 1b, as it is really not needed.

Does our overall process make sense  in your experience of seeing feature implementation for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the necessary processing, the file has to exist online in some form. If the image is being pulled from facebook, dropbox, etc. then it will not be uploaded to S3. However, if the file is local, in order to be processed it must first be uploaded to S3, so there's no way around this step.